# How do I select columns from another table when using group & count? (Rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables:

```
  **Project**

   id
   description
   outcome_id

   **Outcome**
   id
   reference
   description
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences an outcome_id grouped by outcome_id:

```
Project.group(:outcome_id).count(:outcome_id) #I think this is right 
#returns {1=>1, 2=>3}
```

However, I would like to do a join so I can associate the outcome_id with the description of the outcome as well e.g.

```
 Outcome ID Description Count
 1          foobar       1
 2          barfoo       3
```

How do I go about achieving this?

These are my models:

Outcome.rb

```
class Outcome < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :outcome
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `Project.group(:outcome_id).count(:outcome_id).includes(:outcome)` or `Project.group(:outcome_id).count(:outcome_id).joins(:outcome)`?

Comment: Both of those returned errors. Updating question to include models